# Copy snapshot of a WP UI Element containing Scrollbar

Tags: wpf, copy, scrollviewer, snapshot

I have a WPF Uniform Grid containing my custom chart control to be displayed in the form of a matrix. For instance, the grid would display chart controls in 5 x 10 or user defined rows x columns format. The Uniform Grid is placed in a ScrollViewer which automatically shows the scrollbars once the content doesn't fit the window. My intention is to enable 'Copy' of the chart matrix so that the user could paste all the charts in MS Word/Powerpoint.

I have used the standard copy WPF UI Element code. The problem I encountered is that the copy works fine only if all the charts are visible in the Uniform Grid. If I get a scrollbar, the copy would only take into consideration the visible area and replace the invisible area(area below the scrollbar) with Black spot. However, if the user scrolls the bar to view all the content once, then the 'Copy' would work fine(i.e shows all the content in the Grid). I understand that WPF renders the content only when the content is visible.

But, how exactly do I solve my problem without asking my user to view the entire content once, before executing 'Copy'?

Comment: With 'standard copy WPF UI Element code' you mean drawing the UIElement to a RenderTargetBitmap?

Comment: I just did a quick test with 30 Labels in 5 columns in a UniformGrid inside a ScrollViewer. Shrinked the ScrollView so that only a portion of the UniformGrid is visible, then rendered the UniformGrid into a RenderTargenBitmap and encoded into a jpeg file. Works pretty well, i.e. the jpeg contains the whole content. Can you post the code where you render into the RenderTargetBitmap?

Answer (score 0):

1. make window size maximize
2. do "Copy"
3. restore window size

User will notice the window size changing, but at least it is automatic(much better than manually changing window size)